UEFI Secure Boot- enable to use the key to sign the kernel
I am currently trying to set up Secure Boot. However, I'm encountering an issue at the step where I need to use my key to sign my kernel. Interestingly, all previous steps went off without a hitch.
VERSION="$(uname -r)"
 SHORT_VERSION="$(uname -r | cut -d . -f 1-2)"
 MODULES_DIR=/lib/modules/$VERSION
 KBUILD_DIR=/usr/lib/linux-kbuild-$SHORT_VERSION
 sbsign --key MOK.priv --cert MOK.pem "/boot/vmlinuz-$VERSION" --output "/boot/vmlinuz-$VERSION.tmp"
Can't load key from file 'MOK.priv'
40C738CF6B7F0000:error:80000002:system library:BIO_new_file:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(MOK.priv, r)
40C738CF6B7F0000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75:

I tried checking for the existence of the file with the command
ls -l MOK.priv,
but I received the following error message: cannot access 'MOK.priv': No such file or directory".
It appears that the required folder has not been created.

locate MOK.priv gives
/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
But why are you trying to sign a kernel, did you build it yourself?  Normally, you'd install the signed kernels (by Canonical), and just have to sign the third party modules yourself.

@ubfan1 I am following the procedure on the website  https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot[

Are you running Ubuntu, which version?  Debian is off-topic on this site.  Your link is to a not yet created page. Every distribution may do secure boot differently, Ubuntu has a shim signed by Microsoft, Debian doesn't,...

@ubfan1 Every major distribution's build of the shim(https://github.com/rhboot/shim)  source is indirectly signed by Microsoft (via the distribution's signing key, which is signed by Microsoft). I can personally confirm this for Debian, Ubuntu and RockyLinux.
